# How can we track progress of initial load of logical replication in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to track the progress of  inital load of logical replication in postgreSQL means the statistics about how much data data copied, how much data left to copied, any estimation time to complete or any error while copying ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Starting in the soon-to-be-released version, 14, you can use the view `pg_stat_progress_copy` to see the progress of the initial data copy for each table.  It will report the data and tuples already copied, but will not give you that other info.

```
select * from pg_stat_progress_copy ;
  pid  | datid  | datname | relid  |  command  |   type   | bytes_processed | bytes_total | tuples_processed | tuples_excluded 
-------+--------+---------+--------+-----------+----------+-----------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------
 5,884 | 16,384 | jjanes  | 17,014 | COPY FROM | CALLBACK |   1,240,918,397 |           0 |       12,628,295 |               0
```

Comment: Thanks ! is any way to track the progress below version <14

Comment: You can go to the OS, and watch the underlying files grow as they get populated.  Not very effective, but better than nothing.